# Is it safe that JDK 8 uses SHA hash algorithm at KeyStore.load?

Tags: java, security, java-8, cryptography

JDK8 uses the SHA algorithm in its [JavaKeyStore](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/JavaKeyStore.java#L790) class.

From the sources, you see that during `engineLoad` - if a password is given - it generates a SHA MessageDigest based on the provided password. If I get the code correctly, the entries of the keystore are signed with the password in advance. The SHA-Password-MessageDigest is used to check integrity by comparing the stored hashes with the calculated ones - for each entry.

Since SHA is known to be unsafe in certain scenarios, this generates security findings by runtime scanners. Software that uses Java's KeyStore (e.g. [Apache Kafka](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/security/ssl/SslFactory.java)) might be impacted.

I was wondering how bad this security issue is in practice. What attack vectors would be possible?

I'd like to hear assessments of others.

Comment: Ask on [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk This is about an API and requires reading through the Java code to make any kind of assessment of it. I think it is actually better off here.

Comment: IMO this is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), since it's "a practical programming question" (security) that is related to "software tools commonly used by programmers" (JDK) and "software algorithms" (SHA). IMO, none of the off-topic categories apply.

Answer (score 1):

No it is absolutely insecure. It is used whenever the Java KeyStore (.jks) is loaded with a password. It then calculates this poor mans MAC over the read data and then *compares it with a stored stored password hash*.

As it only calculates a SHA-1 over the contents, password and a static magic string `"Mighty Aphrodite"`, it would terribly easy to simply perform e.g. a dictionary or rainbow table attacks. You can even speed this up significantly by simply calculating the data first and storing the intermediate hash value. So it is not insecure because it uses the broken SHA-1 hash so much - *although that is also a concern* - but because it makes it pretty easy to recover the used password. Using PBKDF2 with a high iteration count and a warning in case the security of the password is insufficient would have avoided this issue.

Current SHA-1 attacks still require precalculation and we may assume that the keystore contents are *generally* not precomputed by an adversary. Still, SHA-1 is broken w.r.t. collision resistance so the integrity of the file is *not completely assured*.

I don't see how length extension attacks will make it any worse since the entries are read *before* the password is used, so fortunately it should be OK against those. Replacing the password would however not be an issue at all, which may be used for a social attack (Have you used the wrong password "hi" to protect it? Maybe you should replace that password?).

Note that from Java 9 you should really be using a better key store than JKS (such as a PKCS#12 key store).

Comment: it appears the PKCS12 keystores were supported out of the box at least as far back as Java 6.

Comment: Yeah, but they lacked functionality (basically only accepting private keys with cert chains), which got fixed in 9 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Very good, I believe that is exactly the case.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaDoc specifically says that the intention of this is

> To guard against tampering with the keystore

This all comes down to what your security goals are.

> Since SHA is widely known to be unsafe

SHA is not "unsafe". That is a very over-simplified assessment. It is simply too fast to be useful for hashing *passwords*. It is perfectly "safe" for many other use-cases.

A keystore is not a password, obviously, so the security goals are different. A keystore is a local file. Usually, if a malicious user has physical access to your machine then the battle is already lost.

In this case, the hash is used more for integrity and authenticity than anything else. In which case, SHA is a fine choice.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I rephrased my SHA claim according to your feedback.

Comment: `It is perfectly "safe" for many other use-cases.?` If we assume the SHA means SHA-1 it is not perfectly safe [In 2020, SHA-1 practically broken in chosen-prefix collision (CP-collision). Can double SHA-1 hashing prevent CP-collision?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76879/18298)/ Pre and secondary preimage resistances are ok, however, it not secure against collisions. SHA-1 removed from recommendation around 2011 and ironically this is equal to copyright dates 1997, 2011

Comment: *...In which case, SHA is a fine choice...* and that is also an oversimplified assessment. The hashing construct used here appears to be an ad-hoc MAC technique that uses a password directly; it's never been analyzed, and there is no reason to trust its security without an expert's opinion. I'm not saying it's insecure, but I don't see any analysis to back up your claim that's it's a "fine choice".

Comment: *...so the security goals are different...* That's true, but the attackers #1 goal is the same; recover the unknown password.

Comment: Well, the private keys are protected separately and the integrity protection still has some use. But yeah, not protecting the keystore's password sufficiently is certainly a problem - possibly a huge one.